# Make a picture as a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I make an image in a canvas to act as a link?
I am not able to put < a href > tag on the < image > tag as I dont want it to be displayed first until the user click on a button.

Is there any line of code I need to insert in the javascript?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var endCan = document.getElementById("endCan");
    var end = endCan.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("end");
    end.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 2, img.height / 2);
};
```

```
<img id="end" style="display: none;" src="img/WellDone_Rectangle.png"/>
<canvas id="endCan" class="wrapper" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
```

```
$(".buttonNext6").click(function () {
    $("#endCan").fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add a `onclick`?

Comment: Why are you drawing the image onto a canvas and then fading that in?  You could wrap the image in a link and hide the link initially, and then use `.fadeIn()` to make that fade in instead, which seems like a simpler way to do what you describe.

Comment: @Archer I added a canvas as I want it to be over all the other elements on the page.

Comment: Okay, well the main problem you face is that you're not clicking the image - you're clicking the canvas with a copy of the image on it.  Check my answer below to see if that helps.

Comment: An `img` that you draw onto a canvas becomes a **bunch of pixels**. You can detect a click on a canvas, but in the click handler you'd have to do some math and also know exactly what shapes were drawn where, in order to decide **if** the click was on a shape or not, and then process it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var endCan = document.getElementById("endCan");
    var end = endCan.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("end");
    end.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width / 2, img.height / 2);
};
//$(".buttonNext6").click(function () {
//    $("#endCan").fadeIn();
//});

function canvasCallback() {
    console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<img id="end" style="display: none;" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
<canvas onclick="canvasCallback()" id="endCan" class="wrapper" width="1000" height="600"></canvas>
```

Comment: This needs to be modified.  It shows "clicked" in the console when you click *anywhere* on the canvas, not just the image.  Take the co-ordinate check from my answer and update this.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a click event handler to the canvas, and then when it's clicked you check the co-ordinates to see if it was clicked where your image was drawn.

Here's an example, using a rectangle drawn on a canvas...

```js
var endCan = document.getElementById("endCan");
var endCtx = endCan.getContext("2d");
endCtx.rect(10, 20, 150, 100);
endCtx.fill();

endCan.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.clientX >= 10 && e.clientX <= 160 &&
        e.clientY >= 20 && e.clientY <= 120) {
        alert("clicked");
    }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="endCan" class="wrapper" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```